# Locking and unlocking cells based on value in another cell for tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

So far on the internet, I have seen ways by which one can lock cells in an excel worksheet based on another cell value, however, I am yet to find anything that relates to cases where these cells are contained in a table due to the dynamism table bring about.

Below I have VBA code adapted to suit my own application however it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Worksheets("Nursery").ListObjects("TableName")


If Not Intersect(Target, tbl.ListColumns("Bus Discount").Range) Is Nothing Then
    Dim CellBusDiscount As Range
    Unprotect Password:="Secret"

    For Each CellBusDiscount In Intersect(Target, tbl.ListColumns("Bus Discount").Range)
        Select Case CellBusDiscount.Value
            Case "Yes"
                CellBusDiscount.Offset(0, Application.Worksheet.Function.Match("Bus Reason", tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Bus Discount", tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0)).Locked = False
                CellBusDiscount.Offset(0, Application.Worksheet.Function.Match("Bus Discount Amt", tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Bus Discount", tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0)).Locked = False
            Case "No"
                CellBusDiscount.Offset(0, Application.Worksheet.Function.Match("Bus Reason", tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Bus Discount", tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0)).Locked = True     
                CellBusDiscount.Offset(0, Application.Worksheet.Function.Match("Bus Discount Amt", tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Bus Discount", tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0)).Locked = True
            Case Else
                CellBusDiscount.Offset(0, Application.Worksheet.Function.Match("Bus Reason", tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Bus Discount", tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0)).Locked = True     
                CellBusDiscount.Offset(0, Application.Worksheet.Function.Match("Bus Discount Amt", tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Bus Discount", tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0)).Locked = True
        End Select
    Next cell
    Protect Password:="Secret"
End If 
End Sub
```

Possible reasons why it doesn't work;

1. My VBA knowledge is still very amateur and hence I have not been able to adapt it effectively
2. The Intersect Method used in the code might not work with tables.

What am I trying to achieve exactly with the above code?

I would like to make sure the table columns; `"Bus Discount Amount"` and `"Bus Discount Reason"` are locked is there is **No** Bus discount (i.e. If the value in the `Bus discount` column is **"Yes"** then state the reason for the discount (dropdown list) and enter the amount or have the amount automatically generated depending on the selection in the "Bus Discount Reason")

I have also used the Worksheet Function `Match` to make sure the offset value is dynamic (i.e. if I insert a new table column the cell lock property will remain the same).

Comment: Could it be that you just forgot to start with `ActiveSheet.Unprotect` and finish with `ActiveSheet.Protect`?

Comment: @Jonathan added that but still doesn't run as expected. After every `Bus Discount` cell selection, (i.e. **"Yes"** or **"No"** ) it locks the sheet and it means the user has to reopen the sheet at every instance.

Comment: ok so that is your problem: you have to also start with `cells.Locked = false` to first unlock all cells then lock the one you wish to have locked

Comment: would this line of code come before the `Activesheet.Unprotect` or after and then will there be any need to lock then after protecting the sheet?

Comment: As it seems to be your issue I wrote it as an answer, first unprotect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To activate the locking cells you have to use the protect sheet function:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    Dim tbl As ListObject
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect
  Cells.Locked = false # all cells can be edited (because excel default is Cells.Locked = true)

  #here your code where you set cells to Locked = true 
  ...
  #end of the code

  ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok just a few questions 1. I want to have some table columns locked whether or not the sheet gets unprotected. Is that possible? 2. Also want the default colour of locked cells to be grayed and then if A user chooses a specific value then they have no fill. What I have so far is

Comment: 1. you could use data validation with validation=current cell value. 
2. use `.Interior.Color` or `.Interior.ColorIndex` to change the color of your cells